# Como hacer el feed de instagram en react-native, y que se auto reproduzca solo un video cuando aparezca en pantalla

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

alguno ha hecho el feed estilo de instagram?, donde aparece las imagenes y los videos, y que cuando el video esta en la pantalla se reproduce, y cuando deja de estar en la pantalla se pausa.

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo con el componente `FlatList`, utilizando el prop `onViewableItemsChanged`, donde estoy ejecutando el metodo

```js
  handleViewableItemsChanged(info) {
    console.log("____________________CURRENTS____________-");
    if(info.changed[0].isViewable){
      this.setState({viewableItemCurrent:info.changed[0].item._id});
    }
    console.log(info);
    console.log(this.state);
    
}
```

el cual segun he leido me muestra lo que se encuentra actualmente en la pantalla del celular, donde funciona correctamente.

y la logica que estoy implementando, es que cuando el el video que se este mostrando coincida con algun existente, se reproduzca, pero no esta funcionando, que no se reproduce, pero siento que es porque no se esta actualizando el componente funcional
(O de pronto tienen alguna idea diferente de como pueda realizar esto)

Codigo de el screen feed, donde llamo a los componentes funcionales

```js
class Feed extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.offset= 0;
    this.handleViewableItemsChanged = this.handleViewableItemsChanged.bind(this)
    this.viewabilityConfig = {viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 70}
    this.state={
      user:{},
      publications:[],
      paused:true,
      token:"",
      isloading:true,
      likeselected:false,
      page: 0,
      viewableItemCurrent:''
    };
  }

  handleViewableItemsChanged(info) {
    console.log("____________________CURRENTS____________-");
    if(info.changed[0].isViewable){
      this.setState({viewableItemCurrent:info.changed[0].item._id});
    }
    console.log(info);
    console.log(this.state);
    
}
  _retrieveUserData  = async () =>{
    try {
      const retrievedItem =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@plastic');
      const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
      if(item !== null){
        this.getUserData(item.token);
      }
      else{
        setTimeout(() => {
          Actions.typeUser();
      }, 2000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      
    }
  }
  getUserData = (token) => {
    this.props.meAsync(token)
    .then(res=>{
      
      const respues = res;
      this.setState({user:respues,token:token});
      this.getPublications(token);
    })
    }
  componentDidMount =()=>{
    this._retrieveUserData();
  }
  getPublications =(token)=>{
    this.setState({isloading:true});
    this.props.getApiPublicationsAsync(token)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log('_____________-TRAER PRUBLICACIONES______ 8________')
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({publications: res,isloading:false,viewableItemCurrent:res[8]._id});
    })
    .catch(error=>{
    })
  }

  pausednot=(p)=>{
    console.log(p);
  }

  likedislike=(publication)=>{
    this.props.addremovelike(publication._id,publication,this.state.token)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log("_____::::::::::__________")
      console.log(res);
      this.getPublications(this.state.token);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log('esta es el error', error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <HeaderComponent/> 
        {this.state.isloading   &&
          <LoaderComponent text="Cargando..." />    
        }   
          <View onLayout={this.handleVideoLayout} style={styles.containerpublications}>
            { Array.isArray(this.state.publications) &&
              <FlatList 
                data={this.state.publications}
                onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleViewableItemsChanged}
                viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}

                renderItem={(p)=>{
                console.log('soy p', p, 'tipo: ',p.item.type, 'arreglo completo: ',this.state.publications )
                if(p.item.type===1){
                  console.log('entro if type');
                        if(p.item.media.length>1){
                          console.log('entro al segundo if')
                          return (
                            <Carrusel 
                            key={p.item._id}
                            media={p.item.media}
                            likes={p.item.likes.length}
                            key={p.item._id}
                            image={p.item.media[0].source}
                            publicationInfo={p.item}
                            likely={()=>{
                              this.likedislike(p.item)
                            }} />
                          );
                        }
                }
    else if(p.item.type===2){
      return(
                <ImgVideo
                  key={p.item._id}
                  media={p.item.media}
                  likes={p.item.likes.length}
                  key={p.item._id}
                  image={p.item.media[0].source}
                  publicationInfo={p.item}
                  curritem={this.state.viewableItemCurrent}
                  likely={()=>{
                    this.likedislike(p.item)
                  }} />
              );
            }
            else if(p.item.type===3){
                  return(
                    <ImgImgVideo
                    key={p.item._id}
                    media={p.item.media}
                    likes={p.item.likes.length}
                    key={p.item._id}
                    curritem={this.state.viewableItemCurrent}
                    image={p.item.media[0].source}
                    publicationInfo={p.item}
                    likely={()=>{
                      this.likedislike(p.item)
                    }}  />
                  );
                }


}
        
  }
>
</FlatList>
                 }
              
              </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getApiPublicationsAsync,
  meAsync,
  addremovelike
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Feed)
```

Codigo del componente funcional

```js
export default class ImgVideo extends React.Component{
 
    componentWillReceiveProps(){
        console.log("UPDATED!!!!_____________")
        console.log(this.props.curritem)
    }
    render(){
        return (
            // <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.press}  >
            <View style={styles.containerImgVideo}  >
                <View style={styles.imgVideo}>
                    <Image
                        style={[styles.image, this.props.estilo]}
                        source={{ uri: this.props.media[0].source }}
                    />
                    {
                        this.props.media[1]&& this.props.media[1].type==="video/mp4" &&
                        <Video
                        source={{ uri:this.props.media[1].source }}
                        resizeMode='cover'
                        style={{ width: width / 2, height: height * .4}}
                        paused={this.props.curritem===this.props.publicationInfo._id}
                        muted={this.props.curritem!==this.props.publicationInfo._id}
                        ref={(ref) => {
                            this.player = ref
                        }}
                        repeat={true}
                    />
                    }
                    
                </View>
                <CommentsBox
                    publicationInfo={this.props.publicationInfo}
                    likely={this.props.likely}
                />
            </View>
            // </TouchableOpacity >
        );
    }  
}
ImgVideo.propTypes = {
    publicationInfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    curritem: PropTypes.string
  }
ImgVideo.defaultProps = {
    publicationInfo: [],
    curritem:""
  }
```